# Unable to get VLookup property of WorksheetFunction class

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing a sort of information in excel using VBA and I've got part of it working. what I'm doing is sorting data from one sheet using another and I'm doing an identical process in 3 sets of two sheets that are have different data but an identical format.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub sortButton_Click()
Sheets("Results-SB").Activate
Range("D2").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        Sheets("Results-gs").Activate
Range("D2").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        Sheets("Results-XC").Activate
Range("D2").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal




        Sheets("Results-XC").Activate
Range("D2").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        Sheets("Results-gs").Activate
Range("D2").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        Sheets("Results-XC").Activate
Range("D2").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal



        Sheets("Results-gs").Activate
Range("D2").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        Sheets("Results-gs").Activate
Range("D2").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        Sheets("Results-XC").Activate
Range("D2").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal



Dim rcount1, rcount2, t As Long
Dim rcount3 As Long

Dim sh1, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim score

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh1 = Sheets("CompetitorSB")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Results-SB")



rcount1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
rcount2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For t = 2 To rcount2



If sh1.Range("B" & t).Value Like "*M50*" Then

        rcount2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        sh1.Range("D" & t).Copy sh2.Range("I" & rcount2 + 1)

        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            score = .VLookup(sh1.Range("D" & t).Value, sh2.Columns("A:D"), 4, 0)
            sh2.Range("J" & rcount2 + 1).Value = score
        End With

        ElseIf sh1.Range("B" & t).Value Like "*W50*" Then

        rcount2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        sh1.Range("D" & t).Copy sh2.Range("I" & rcount2 + 1)

        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            score = .VLookup(sh1.Range("D" & t).Value, sh2.Columns("A:D"), 4, 0)
            sh2.Range("J" & rcount2 + 1).Value = score
        End With

           ElseIf sh1.Range("B" & t).Value Like "*W*" Then
        rcount2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        sh1.Range("D" & t).Copy sh2.Range("F" & rcount2 + 1)
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            score = .VLookup(sh1.Range("D" & t).Value, sh2.Columns("A:D"), 4, 0)
            sh2.Range("G" & rcount2 + 1).Value = score
        End With



    End If
Next t

 For Each rngRow In sh2.Range("F2:G4").Rows
 rngRow.Font.Bold = True
 Next rngRow
 For Each rngRow In sh2.Range("I2:J4").Rows
 rngRow.Font.Bold = True
 Next rngRow

 <---------------------------- Up until here everything is working perfectly


 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh1 = Sheets("CompetitorGS")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Results-gs")



rcount1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
rcount2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For t = 2 To rcount2



If sh1.Range("B" & t).Value Like "*M50*" Then

        rcount2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        sh1.Range("D" & t).Copy sh2.Range("I" & rcount2 + 1)

        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            score = .VLookup(sh1.Range("D" & t).Value, sh2.Columns("A:D"), 4, 0)
            sh2.Range("J" & rcount2 + 1).Value = score
        End With

        ElseIf sh1.Range("B" & t).Value Like "*W50*" Then

        rcount2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        sh1.Range("D" & t).Copy sh2.Range("I" & rcount2 + 1)

        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            score = .VLookup(sh1.Range("D" & t).Value, sh2.Columns("A:D"), 4, 0)
            sh2.Range("J" & rcount2 + 1).Value = score
        End With

           ElseIf sh1.Range("B" & t).Value Like "*W*" Then
        rcount2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        sh1.Range("D" & t).Copy sh2.Range("F" & rcount2 + 1)
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            score = .VLookup(sh1.Range("D" & t).Value, sh2.Columns("A:D"), 4, 0)' VLOOKUP GENERALLY FAILS HERE
            sh2.Range("G" & rcount2 + 1).Value = score
        End With



    End If
Next t

 For Each rngRow In sh2.Range("F2:G4").Rows
 rngRow.Font.Bold = True
 Next rngRow
 For Each rngRow In sh2.Range("I2:J4").Rows
 rngRow.Font.Bold = True
 Next rngRow



End Sub
```

When sh1 and sh2 are set the "SB" sheets this works exactly as intended, but when I try to perform the same sort on either the "GS" or "XC" sets, I get a vlookup error.
In the "GS" set It sorts a decent amount before crashing but if I try to do this using the "XC" sheets, it changes cell F:2 to have a 1 in it and that's it.
I can't think why this happens because the only difference between these sheets is the amount of data/lines, format-wise they are identical.
I've been googling and swapping/rewriting code for a couple hours now and still haven't made any headway. any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? Which cells specifically do they fail at on the second and third sheets?

Comment: **describe the specific problem — and include VALID code to reproduce it**. *we are not interested in your entire macro*

Comment: The last data entered for the "GS" set is in cell F:23, If F has data G should as well but G:23 is blank.

Comment: the "XC" set always ends on the first line, if I remove the 'if' for "*W*" then it fills in the first unused row (I:2) with an 8. if that 'if' isn't removed, than it is F:2 with a 1.

Comment: @mehow - I included the entire macro because I don't know what's causing the specific problem. I was told by a friend that data used by vlookup should be sorted in ascending order so I included the code that showed that said rows had been sorted.

Comment: @Deoff well, we require a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved** from askers :)

Comment: You don't need to sort your data if using the "exact" option for vlookup (ie. when the last parameter is 0)

Answer (score 0):

You will find it easier to drop the `Worksheetfunction` and just use `Application.Vlookup`: then you can test the return value for an error instead of having the vlookup throw an error if it doesn't find the value.

```
Dim score As Variant

score = Application.VLookup(sh1.Range("D" & t).Value, sh2.Columns("A:D"), 4, 0)
sh2.Range("J" & rcount2 + 1).Value = iif(iserror(score), "Not found", score)
```

As noted in my comment above, there's no need to sort the data if you're using the "exact match" option for vlookup.